# How to cache resources in Asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching

My Requirement is i need to Cache all the assets such as Images,Script,Css. Because these are all static. Whenever we browse we don't need to reload again. How can i do this Asp.net MVC. Is there is any mechanism in MVC?

Comment: Caching mechanism is available for all web technolojies(not only mvc), I think, first, you should research about this topic...

Comment: not server data..I need to cache all the static data in a webpage

Comment: i got many informations from sites..Some are saying caching from IIS and others saying by programmatically.Which is the best method? is there any other techniques other than these things?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure Http Caching in IIS for your content folders. There is nothing you should do in the code (unless you are using bundling).

The easiest way of doing this would be to open `HTTP Response Headers` section in IIS Manager for that folder, click `Set Common Header...` and enable the `Expire Web Content` section and specify it to expire, for example, after 1 hour.

Comment: which is the method for caching usinf IIS or Programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

I concur that it is important to first get more information on caching and what options and budget you have available:

http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/09/01/pfint_distributed-caching.aspx

You may also want to take a peak at NCache:

http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/